# Can't get access token in android using retrofit but works only in curl

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit, spring-data-rest, retrofit2

I have a problem with retrofit in android when I try to get the access token it doesn't work at all and I get "unauthorized 401" but using DHC byRESTlet I can get the access token without any problem.

[image]

This is the interface I use :

```
public interface TokenService {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization : Basic dGVzdDo="
    })
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token")
    Call<TokenEntity> getAccessToken(@Field("username") String username,
                                     @Field("password") String password ,
                                     @Field("grant_type") String grantType );
}
```

and this is log error :

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.1.5:8080/oauth/token http/1.1
     D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 52
     D/OkHttp: Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     D/OkHttp: Authorization : Basic dGVzdDo=
     D/OkHttp: username=abcd&password=aqwzsx123&grant_type=password
     D/OkHttp: --> END POST (52-byte body)
     D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://192.168.1.5:8080/oauth/token (21ms)
     D/OkHttp: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
     D/OkHttp: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
     D/OkHttp: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
     D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
     D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
     D/OkHttp: Expires: 0
     D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: DENY
     D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store
     D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
     D/OkHttp: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="oauth", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"
     D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
     D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 07:44:03 GMT
     D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1462520643079
     D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1462520643087
     D/OkHttp: {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
<-- END HTTP (102-byte body)
ponse{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=http://192.168.1.5:8080/oauth/token}
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not seem like retrofit problem.

You may try using @Body instead of fields, try making class:

```
class Request {
  String username;
  ...
}
```

and then

```
Call<TokenEntity> getAccessToken(@Body Request request);
```

Comment: That was my first try but it seems like to get /oauth/token I should have "formurlEncode" annotation and to use it I should use @Field otherwise I get error. Anyway weirdly the error got fixed I just removed space in Headers annotation.